# High error machine learning regressor algorithm in Python - XGBOOST Regressor

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, data-science, xgboost

I have a dataframe with real state data from florida, it includes single apartments and buildings data:

[image]

```
'TRUE_SITE_CITY': The city where the building is. variable: Miami, Aventura...;
'CONDO_FLAG': If it is a condominium or not, variable: yes/no;
'BEDROOM_COUNT': Number of total bethrooms, variable: integuer,
'BUILDING_actual_AREA': The area of the entire building, or apartment in the case that there are only one apartment or house. variable: integuer;
'FLOOR_COUNT': Number of the floors that the building has;
'DOR_CODE_CUR': the type of the building. Variable: categorical;
'UNIT_COUNT': Number of apartments or houses in the building. Variable: integuer;
'YEAR_BUILT': Year that the building or house or apartment was build: Variable: categorical;
'public_transport_min_distance': I have calculated the nearest stations of the public transport;
'Price': The variable that I want to predict.
```

I have done an exploratory data analysis and I have dropped some data that has null values and some data that was incorrect. Also I have dropped the values with outliers.

The basic statistics of the price column (targeted column):

[image]

I have checked the categorical features and they have enough variables in each one to keep them in the model.

I have done a pipeline to make a one hot encoder for the categorical values and a standard standardisation for the numerical values. In it I have include a XGBOOST regression:

```
from xgboost import XGBRegressor
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_validate
from sklearn import metrics
from sklearn import preprocessing, feature_extraction
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn import preprocessing, feature_extraction
from sklearn.pipeline import make_pipeline, make_union
from mlxtend.feature_selection import ColumnSelector
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from category_encoders import OneHotEncoder

x_numeric = df_x[['BEDROOM_COUNT','BATHROOM_COUNT',
       'HALF_BATHROOM_COUNT', 'FLOOR_COUNT','UNIT_COUNT','public_transport_min_distance','BUILDING_actual_AREA']]

x_categorical = df_x[['TRUE_SITE_CITY','CONDO_FLAG','YEAR_BUILT']]

categorical_col = x_categorical.columns

numeric_col = x_numeric.columns

estimator_pipeline = Pipeline([
    ('procesador', procesing_pipeline),
    ('estimador', estimator)
])

score2 = cross_validate(estimator_pipeline, X= df_x, y= df_y, scoring=scoring,return_train_score=False, cv=5,n_jobs=2)
```

But I am obtaining a high error. The mean value of the price is almost 200.000 and the error that I obtain is:

[image]

I have done feature selection using RFE but I obtain a high error as well.

Also I have run it doing RandomizedSearchCV

```
from sklearn.model_selection import RandomizedSearchCV

params = {"estimator__learning_rate"    : [0.05, 0.10, 0.15, 0.20, 0.25, 0.30 ] ,
 "estimator__max_depth"        : [ 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 10, 12, 15],
 "estimator__min_child_weight" : [ 1, 3, 5, 7 ],
 "estimator__gamma"            : [ 0.0, 0.1, 0.2 , 0.3, 0.4 ],
 "estimator__colsample_bytree" : [ 0.3, 0.4, 0.5 , 0.7 ] }

random_search = RandomizedSearchCV(
    estimator=estimator_pipeline, 
    param_distributions=params, cv=5, refit=True,
    scoring="neg_mean_squared_error", n_jobs= 3,
    return_train_score=True,
    n_iter=50)
```

But I obtain a similar error value.

What could I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few remarks/suggestions from my side. Hope it will help you.

1. do not use YEAR_BUILT variable as a categorical one but rather use it as numercial variable, you can also tranform this variable into new one describing the age of building/apartment and then you can try different transformations,
2. you can try to increase the number of independent variables by adding different variables being the transformations of the current ones for example by using the square values
3. in general taking into account that you have only 9 independent variables and large dataset I will focus on creating new potential variables
4. using algorithms that somehow based on the decision trees approach you do not have to perform standardisation for numerical variable
5. using different boosting algorithms you should rather focus on base estimators (shallow decision trees)
6. try different algorithms (for example simple decision tree or random forest) to compare the results

Comment: Thanks for the answer!

2. What do you mean with square values?

Comment: I thought about the preparing new idependent variable that will be the square of the current one for example you could prepare the new variable BEDROOM_COUNT_SQUARE = BEDROOM_COUNT * BEDROOM_COUNT.
However in case you are going to use the algorithm that based on the decision trees and you have only positive values I was wrong and it will not change a lot becasue the algorithm will find the same split but with the squared value.

Comment: I think that in this case it will be helpful to prepare some 2-dimensional independent variable for example variable BEDROOM_COUNT x FLOOR_COUNT or something similar, but first I would try to perform some EDA for the selected variables then I would decide if I want to perform binning for selected variables before I will try to use them together. Decision tree algorithm analyse only one variable for the specific split so by creating new variables that consist of two or more independent variables we can find some new splits.

Comment: With shallow decision trees, you mean to put the hyper parameter max_depth a lower number?

Comment: Yes, you can even use max_depth equals 1. Let know if you were able to reach better results.